# sql query group by departname with details in other table

Tags: mysql

**Table: Employee**

```
EmpID: INTEGER NOT NULL
DeptID: INTEGER NOT NULL
Name: Char(40) NOT NULL
Age: INTEGER NOT NULL
Salary: INTEGER NOT NULL
```

**Table: Department**

```
DeptID: INTEGER NOT NULL
Name: CHAR(20) NOT NULL
```

We need to write an SQL query which outputs names of all the departments such that the average salary of the department is greater than 10,00,000. The output should contain only one column: `DeptName`.

Tried this:

```
SELECT AVG(Salary) AS avg_salary ,DeptID FROM ( SELECT DeptID, Salary FROM employee GROUP BY 1) DeptID GROUP BY DeptID HAVING avg_salary > 10;
```

Result: unable to join.

Comment: homework? what have you tried so far?

Comment: SELECT AVG(Salary) AS avg_salary ,DeptID FROM (  SELECT DeptID, Salary
                        FROM employee
                    GROUP BY 1) DeptID GROUP BY  DeptID HAVING  avg_salary > 10; unable to join

Answer (score 0):

Here's the query:

```
SELECT 
Department.name AS DeptName
FROM Department 
INNER JOIN Employee ON Department.DeptID = Employee.DeptID
GROUP BY Department.DeptID
HAVING AVG(Employee.Salary) > 1000000;
```

Comment: Write an SQL query which produces a list of department names, and the oldest employee in that department. In case more than one employee have the highest age in any department, then there should be one output row for each such employee. Departments that do not have any employees should not appear in the output. The output should only contain two columns: DeptName, and OldestEmpName, in that order ;)

Comment: Are you intending to make all your home works done by others? I didn't see any zeal to learn in you. It made me upset.

Comment: yeah i know it is not good ,i always intend to work hard but the clock is ticking .. anyways thanks ..